# how to sort result by giving different weight to each column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, logic

I want to sort my result from a sql database (mysql or sql server). but there are more than one column that each column has different weight to sort for example

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 FROM mytable ORDER BY (F1*2+F2*7+F3)
```

but i afraid it takes too long to process because my database can have millions of records so sorting that amount of data and calculating that formula for all record could be very slow how can i do this more faster??

EDIT: these weight number is not constant

Comment: You can add a new indexed column _weight_ and create a trigger that calculates the value on every insert/update. Then just order by _weight_.

Answer (score 2):

If your numbers are constant then create a `computed column`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
   ADD O_ComputedColumn AS (F1*2+F2*7+F3) PERSISTED
```

[**Here**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/21/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-storage-part-2/) is some advantages of making your computed column `Persisted`

Query:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY O_ComputedColumn
```

and this is for `Sql Server`. I never tried it give it a try

Comment: I tried it, it works. I like this simple solution. Just save the computation

Comment: my number is not constant because i get them from users

Answer (score 1):

@MM93,idea was good.
See,there is 2 more way of achieving this.but both require little more info.

1.Pull all the desire rows without sorting.Then sort it in front end.This may be fast.

1. write your query like this,
2. SELECT F1,F2,F3,F1*2+F2*7+F3 as NewColumn FROM mytable

Then sort it in front end.